# Extending a Laravel Vendor Controller Class laravel-saml2 Saml2Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, saml-2.0, extends

I am new to Laravel and I am including Laravel 24slides/laravel-saml2 package in my Laravel 8 app and trying to extend the Saml2Controller Class to have more control on how to use its functions.

```
Error:
(OneLogin\\Saml2\\Error(code: 0): Settings file not found: ****/vendor/onelogin/php-saml/settings.php at ****/vendor/onelogin/php-saml/src/Saml2/Settings.php:311)
```

I think I am missing a step or two. I have search on here how to do this and came up short.

This is my controller extending Saml2Controller Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Slides\Saml2\Http\Controllers\Saml2Controller;

class MySaml2Controller extends Saml2Controller
{
    // code here
}
```

Looking around and putting some logs, when I use my `MySaml2Controller` It does not run the `Slides\Saml2` `OneLoginBuilder.php` so it does not pick the settings array from `config/saml2.php`.

```
<?php

namespace Slides\Saml2;

use OneLogin\Saml2\Auth as OneLoginAuth;
use OneLogin\Saml2\Utils as OneLoginUtils;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use Slides\Saml2\Models\Tenant;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

/**
 * Class OneLoginBuilder
 *
 * @package Slides\Saml2
 */
class OneLoginBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * The resolved tenant.
     *
     * @var Tenant
     */
    protected $tenant;

    /**
     * OneLoginBuilder constructor.
     *
     * @param Container $app
     */
    public function __construct(Container $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Set a tenant.
     *
     * @param Tenant $tenant
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function withTenant(Tenant $tenant)
    {
        $this->tenant = $tenant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap the OneLogin toolkit.
     *
     * @param Tenant $tenant
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function bootstrap()
    {
        if ($this->app['config']->get('saml2.proxyVars', false)) {
            OneLoginUtils::setProxyVars(true);
        }

        $this->app->singleton('OneLogin_Saml2_Auth', function ($app) {
            $config = $app['config']['saml2'];

            $this->setConfigDefaultValues($config);

            $oneLoginConfig = $config;
            $oneLoginConfig['idp'] = [
                'entityId' => $this->tenant->idp_entity_id,
                'singleSignOnService' => ['url' => $this->tenant->idp_login_url],
                'singleLogoutService' => ['url' => $this->tenant->idp_logout_url],
                'x509cert' => $this->tenant->idp_x509_cert
            ];

            $oneLoginConfig['sp']['NameIDFormat'] = $this->resolveNameIdFormatPrefix($this->tenant->name_id_format);
            logger(['OneLoginBuilder oneLoginConfig', $oneLoginConfig['sp']]);
            return new OneLoginAuth($oneLoginConfig);
        });

        $this->app->singleton('Slides\Saml2\Auth', function ($app) {
            return new \Slides\Saml2\Auth($app['OneLogin_Saml2_Auth'], $this->tenant);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set default config values if they weren't set.
     *
     * @param array $config
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setConfigDefaultValues(array &$config)
    {
        foreach ($this->configDefaultValues() as $key => $default) {
            if(!Arr::get($config, $key)) {
                Arr::set($config, $key, $default);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Configuration default values that must be replaced with custom ones.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function configDefaultValues()
    {
        return [
            'sp.entityId' => URL::route('saml.metadata', ['uuid' => $this->tenant->uuid]),
            'sp.assertionConsumerService.url' => URL::route('saml.acs', ['uuid' => $this->tenant->uuid]),
            'sp.singleLogoutService.url' => URL::route('saml.sls', ['uuid' => $this->tenant->uuid])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Resolve the Name ID Format prefix.
     *
     * @param string $format
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function resolveNameIdFormatPrefix(string $format): string
    {
        switch ($format) {
            case 'emailAddress':
            case 'X509SubjectName':
            case 'WindowsDomainQualifiedName':
            case 'unspecified':
                return 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:' . $format;
            default:
                return 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:'. $format;
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to make this `OneLoginBuilder.php` to run so settings will not be missing. It does not run when I use `MySaml2Controller` in the routes.

Putting a settings file in this location `/vendor/onelogin/php-saml/` will remove the error but this get overridden when there is an composer update. Settings file is created inside the `OneLoginBuilder.php` coming from `condfig/saml2.php` file.

Or is there a better way to do this than extending the `laravel-saml2` controller class?

I am new to using Laravel so any tips on how to solve this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why is there backthicks on your controller name? The error says there is a missing file on package folder. So there is nohing you can do.

Comment: did you publish the configuration file?  also the error is coming from the package that this package is using so seems some configuration isn't right

Comment: I edited the question to remove the back ticks on the controller names. The config files is store in the config('saml') file and works fine using the default `Saml2Controller` of the 24slides laravel-saml2.